# Laptop Power Supply with detachable cables

Tags: laptop, power-supply, power

I have an Acer laptop which gets a lot of use. The problem is the charger. Due to wear and tear the cable has split (see photo). I could easily get a replacement power supply, but I'm wondering if there are power supplies where the mains power cable and the cable to the computer are both detachable. A search on the net revealed that there are some power supplies with this feature for ASUS computers - e.g. ASUS N90W-03 ADAPTER. So far no luck for the Acer. The output the Acer power supply is 19V and 4.74A. A generic power supply could would be ok as long as it met my wattage and cable requirements.

[[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pk3nC.jpg)

Comment: Is that the wire to the wall or the one to the laptop?  It doesn't appear that any internal wires are actually broken.  If that's the case, you could just use something like Sugru or Oogoo to seal, insulate, and reinforce it.

Comment: Is there any reason why those are not 3 components ((1) outlet to transformer (2) transformer (3) transfomer to laptop)? [I'm also pretty annoyed by this](https://twitter.com/_martinthoma/status/1500576086626816006)

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen one physically where the entire cable from the power supply to the laptop is detachable (in fact, even the one you've linked I'm not convinced is, as I couldn't find any images or reference to suggest it does come apart? Even the ASUS website lists it as being a package of: Adapter*1+Power Cord*1 - suggesting one cable detaches and the other is fixed to the adapter).

I have done a quick search and returned [this](http://www.bestbuy.com/site/retrak-universal-laptop-charger-black/4217400.p?id=1219708511642&skuId=4217400) but I don't trust the look of that cable at all. I'd just stick with a fixed one, as I doubt getting a replacement part if the cable got damaged would actually be that easy to find anyway.